# django 1.6 serving static admin files using alias with apache

Tags: django, apache

So I am converting the Django tutorial to fully work with Apache instead of using the built-in "runserver" command.  I got step one working; getting Apache to serve the static files (css).  Now I need to get it to serve the static files for the admin.

My code so far in the httpd.conf file for Apache 2.4.

```
#static files for site
Alias /static/ "C:/mysite/polls/static/"
<Directory "C:/mysite/polls/static">
Require all granted
</Directory>

#static files for admin
Alias /static/ "C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/"
<Directory "C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static">
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Obviously having the same alias for the 2nd block does not work and the CSS will not load for the admin.  The site (1st block) loads fine.  Now this page in the Django tutorial details the entire process on how to make it work.  I just cannot figure it out.  Maybe I am doing a syntax error and I have read countless posts about this both here and elsewhere.

The doc mentions 3 ways to do it.  I want to do it the 2nd way; by way of using the alias directive: "Use an Alias directive, as demonstrated above, to alias the appropriate URL (probably STATIC_URL + admin/) to the actual location of the admin files."

Now I don't understand the exact part where it says "STATIC_URL + admin/).  I tried various variations of that but it won't work.  My link to the admin page is exactly this:
`http://127.0.0.1/admin/`

Can we figure this out in specific to WINDOWS and DJANGO 1.6?  I know prior to DJANGO 1.4 there was a different way using "ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX" in the settings.py file.  That way is deprecated now and I want to use the alias.  And bonus.  How do aliases exactly work?

Thanks all.

EDIT:
Link that mentions how to do it.  Under "Serving the admin files" I need to figure out the 2nd way using alias.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/

Answer (score 1):

This is what the "static" app is for. You should do `manage.py collectstatic` on deployment, and this collects all your static content - both for your apps and for the built-in/contrib ones - into one place, which is where you point your Apache alias to.

But if you really want to hard code it, STATIC_URL + admin just means exactly that: the value of STATIC_URL, suffixed with "admin", so `Alias /static/admin`.

Comment: `Alias /static/admin "C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/"
<Directory "C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static">
Require all granted

</Directory>`

Did exactly that to hard-code it.  It still won't load CSS.  Something is off...

Comment: I don't understand why you won't use collectstatic, though. It is meant exactly to solve this problem.

Comment: I will use that to deploy. I just want to use Apache instead of Django's server for development. This is just a development environment and not for prod. Thanks for the advise and I learned a bit.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that finally works:

```
Alias /static/admin "C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/"
<Directory "C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin">
Require all granted
</Directory>

Alias /static/ "C:/mysite/polls/static/"
<Directory "C:/mysite/polls/static">
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Note that ORDER matters greatly.  I have to Alias the admin static BEFORE aliasing the site static.  Sounds like a cascading type issue and makes sense the more specific gets precedent.

Also I had my link incorrect for the admin.  It was ending in ..`/admin/static/`.  It should go deeper into ..`/admin/static/admin/`.

Finally 2 areas working to serve static files.  The admin comes first and then the site static 2nd.

Thanks to all and this should be really documented and might be a pitfall for some.